# Why are only lattice problems used in cryptography?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, complexity, lattice-crypto

There are thousands of NP-hard problems out there. Why have only lattice problems been applied to cryptography?

Comment: It's not NP-hard problems what people are looking for to begin with

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But now it's called "post-quantum age".I think the base of the cryptographic primitives should be built on NP-hard problems.Whether it's hard to find some useful property like average-case hardness  on other NP-hard problems?

Comment: I've rephrased the question title, it looked that lattice problems were only used for cryptography, not for other math related problems. That's of course not what was asked.

Comment: "Why have only lattice problems been applied to cryptograhpy?" What happened to MQ-based, code-based and hash-based?

Answer (score 22):

What makes a problem suitable for cryptography is slightly different than what makes a problem NP-hard.

What is required for cryptography is average-case hardness --- i.e., a randomly selected instance of a problem should be "hard" for an adversary to solve. However, random instances of some NP-hard problems (3SAT, e.g.) turn out to be [easy](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/research/danny.vilenchik/papers/2006/ExpectedPoly3SAT.pdf) with high probability.

Lattices are interesting as some of its average-case hard problems (ex. Shortest Integer Solution, SIS) allow a [reduction](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lattice-survey.pdf) to worst-case hard problems (ex. Shortest Independent Vector Problem, SIVP) --- i.e. solving a random instance of one problem is as hard as solving worst-case instance of another. No *efficient* quantum algorithms are known against these problems either.

Moreover, lattices have enough underlying algebraic structure which allows building cryptographic primitives (OWFs, Trapdoors, FHEs...) based on these hard problems --- see the [survey](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/lattice-survey.pdf) by Peikert.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I know that there are  many useful properties on Lattices like average-case  hardness .But just like decoding of random  linear code,it has average-case  hardness naturally.And I don't know whether some other problems maybe with some good algebraic structure have those good property which are needed in  cryptography?

Comment: Cryptography based on [multivariate polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_cryptography) is another example --- their worst-case--average-case relationship is not known though.

Comment: "Moreover, no quantum algorithms are known against these problems." - No *polynomial time* quantum algorithms...

Answer (score 5):

See

- [1:stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311064/are-there-public-key-cryptography-algorithms-that-are-provably-np-hard-to-defeat)
- [2:cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/why-hasnt-there-been-an-encryption-algorithm-that-is-based-on-the-known-np-hard),
- [3:On the possibility of basing Cryptography on the assumption that P!=NP](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjDsanRkILTAhXRZpoKHfmLCk0QFggcMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Feprint.iacr.org%2F1998%2F005.ps&usg=AFQjCNHnYMBDinehGLODCzKK64Miqk5o7w&sig2=0JpVYjF2txZOxXuv1cgy3w) and
- (before Ajtai) [4:A Personal View of Average-Case Complexity (Impagliazzo 1995)](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~russell/average.ps).
- [5:Average case complexity (Trevisan,Bogdanov)](https://arxiv.org/ps/cs/0606037v2)

It seems that this is an open problem : "if we can base cryptography in $P\not= NP$". 
Also as the previous poster wrote there are some other problems except lattices as : multivariate crypto (J.Patarin scheme) and problems based on codes (McEliece cryptosystem).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at the Post-quantum Cryptography book by Bernstain, Dahmen, and Buchmann. There are more problems used in post-quantum crypto than just lattice problems:

- Security of symmetric primitives,
- problems from coding theory,
- the MQ problem, and quite recently
- problems of isogenies.

Some of the problems are NP-hard (which only refers to the worst-case as mentioned in the other answer), some are not. In any case, even for lattice-based cryptography we actually do not make use of the worst-case hardness in practice. Parameters in practice are never chosen such that the related worst-case instance is actually hard (at least I am not aware of any case).

Comment: While this is an old post, you're right. Parameters are chosen such that that the underlying worst-case hard problem is $\mathsf{SVP}_\gamma$ or $\mathsf{SIVP}_\gamma$ (approximate shortest vector problem/shortest independent vector problem). The approximation factor $\gamma$ (that we can get worst-case to average case reductions for) is $>\sqrt{n}$ (where $n$ is the dimension of the lattice), but SVP is known to be in coNP for that approximation factor, so cannot be NP-hard unless NP = coNP.